# How to express some tangential force in terms of mg

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, physics

I am trying to express some force F_h in terms of mg but the reuslt I get is wrong the equations are the following:

$$\Sigma F_x = N_2-f1 = 0$$
$$\Sigma F_y = f2 + N_1-mg-F_h = 0$$

$$\Sigma\tau = -\frac{1}{2}Lmg\sin\theta - LF_h\sin\theta + LN_2\cos\theta+Lf_2\sin\theta = 0$$

notice how using the first two equation I express N_2 in terms of mg and F_h hence:

$$N_2 = \frac{\mu(mg + F_h)}{\mu^2+1}$$

solving for F_h in the third equation and plug in the new N_2 eq I get:

$$F_h =mg \frac{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\mu \cot\theta+\mu^2}{\mu^2+1}}{1 +\frac{\cot\theta-\mu}{\mu^2+1}}$$

since the angle is 40° and μ is 0.4 I get:

$$F_h = mg0.45$$

however this is wrong the correct answer is:
$$F_h = mg0.11$$

what did I get wrong?

for the context this equations are the static equilibrium of a meter stick with some upper angle 40° and μ 0.4 and I am trying to see how hard can I press down vertically on the top of the stick with a hand before slipping begins thats why I am trying to solve for F_h force of hand. notice how I use the point of contact of the stick with the ground as pivot in the torque equation.

Comment: note f2 = μN_2. and f1 = μN_1

Comment: f2 is the friccion of the stick against the wall and f1 is the friccion of the stick againts the floor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression for $N_2$ is correct, but there are some algebra mistakes when substituting it in and solving for $F_h$. Notice that:
$$
F_h
= \frac{LN_2 \cos \theta + L(\mu N_2)\sin\theta - 0.5Lmg\sin\theta}{L\sin\theta}
= (\cot\theta + \mu)N_2 - 0.5mg
$$
Substituting, we have:
\begin{align*}
F_h &= (\cot\theta + \mu) \cdot \frac{\mu}{\mu^2 + 1}(mg + F_h) - 0.5mg \\
F_h &= \frac{\mu(\cot\theta + \mu)}{\mu^2 + 1}(mg + F_h) - 0.5mg \\
F_h - \frac{\mu(\cot\theta + \mu)}{\mu^2 + 1}F_h &= \frac{\mu(\cot\theta + \mu)}{\mu^2 + 1}mg - 0.5mg \\
F_h &= \frac{\dfrac{\mu(\cot\theta + \mu)}{\mu^2 + 1} - 0.5}{1 - \dfrac{\mu(\cot\theta + \mu)}{\mu^2 + 1}} mg =(0.108354\ldots)mg
\end{align*}

Comment: what did you do in step 2 of substituting?

Comment: In Step 1, notice that the first term looks like $(\textsf{stuff})(mg + F_h)$. I expanded this to be $(\textsf{stuff})mg + (\textsf{stuff})F_h$, then subtracted $(\textsf{stuff})F_h$ to the other side of the equation.

Comment: thank you sir...